# How can i create a more optimize 2d tile map (see the image of tile map)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine

I am looking to create a tile map similar as the image below [image]

=> One way of doing is to create an image in photoShop.

---

=> other way is to create multiple gameobject in a scene and arrange them in such a maner to create such type of image

---

=> third way is to get the vertices of every edge and create a mesh from a single script .

---

I have a game were there is multiple Level of different map which method will be more efficient and optimize and why ? what are the advantage and disadvantage of using these method

---

Also how can i create that border in the image If i don't use PhotoShop .One way is to use line renderer but is that efficient ? if not what are the other possible soultion

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should consider what does the map have in addition to graphics. Does it have moving parts? Trigger areas? Other characters? Do they interact with each other? The more static the map, the more sttic the implementation can be.

If the game is relatively simple, you can use a GameObject for each element, and performance will be fine.

Now, you are also asking how to define a map. One way is to create a prefab foe each map, and instance the right prefab when you load the selected map. Thatś good if each map is different, but making general changes to all maps is a major pain.

Another option is to define an XML or script with the elements of each map, which then you parse or run when you want to load a map. It's considerably more complicated to do, but then the map elements are independent of the map, so you can redraw scenes with more precision.